# How can you determine which servlet matches a URL when inside a servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters

I am running a Jetty web server and I have a generic servlet filter to handle exceptions.  As part of this, I want to log aggregated metrics about which servlets are causing the exceptions.  Is there a way I can figure out which servlets defined in the web.xml match the servlet path of the current request?

Comment: An exception should be just that, an exception. You check the logs, look at the stacktrace to identify the servlet that threw the exception, and you fix the code so it doesn't occur anymore. Do you have so many exceptions that you want to build aggregated metrics about them? Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a generic servlet filter to handle exceptions

I take you to mean that your filter extends `javax.servlet.GenericFilter` directly.

> Is there a way I can figure out which servlets defined in the web.xml match the servlet path of the current request?

In any given servlet context there should not be more than one servlet mapped to a given servlet path, so in any given case you're looking for just one servlet, not multiple.

As far as I know or can tell, `GenericFilter` and the generic `ServletRequest`s and `ServletResponse`s with which it works do not provide a good way to access the information you are after.  If you cast the request to `HttpServletRequest`, however, then you can obtain its [`HttpServletMapping`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping.html) (since Servlet 4.0 / Java EE 8)
, which contains the servlet name as declared in the webapp's deployment descriptor, among other information.  Or the `HttpServletRequest` can directly provide the servlet path, too.

But if you are contemplating casting the requests, then you would probably be better off having your filter extend `javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter`, which would give you type-safe access.  This is itself a subclass of `GenericFilter`, so it probably wouldn't be difficult to perform such a refactoring.